# Как задать разные шаблоны компонентов для разных элементов Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Ссылка на детальную страницу выглядит следующим образом: site.ru/blabla/bloblo/?ELEMENT_ID=1282

Самих элементов много, но для трех из них нужно задать свой шаблон детальной страницы.
Пробовал делать вот так

```
if (strstr(CSite::InDir(true), 'blabla/bloblo/?ELEMENT_ID=1282') !== false) {$SP = 'news-comissii';};
```

Но в таком виде я так понимаю можно задать только шаблон для раздела, как указать что для элемента с ID=1282 был определённый шаблон?

Comment: Взять шаблон `template.php` и в нем уже написать что-то типа `if (arResult[id] == A) { такая html-разметка } else { другая html-разметка }`

Comment: А, то есть в `template.php` добавляю условие и если оно совпадает то `{ такая html-разметка }` сюда я вставляю верстку одного шаблона, а если нет то другого. Верно? Если все так то это еще проще чем я думал)))) Всё гениальное просто!

Comment: Да, всё получилось! Спасибо большое

Comment: Условия в template.php не рекомендуется пихать. Аналогичное условие можно пихнуть в вызове компонента


if(ELEMENT_ID == 135){
$templ="catalog_red";
}
else
{
$templ="catalog_green";}

$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:catalog", $templ, array(),false);